# How to present some VC at modalVC's parent VC without hierarchy warnings?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, hierarchy, popover

I try to present VCs but buttons in popover menu, but I have hierarchy warnings like this:

> Warning: Attempt to present "UIViewController: 0x14def7500" on "MyProject.MainViewController: 0x14f976400" whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I have MainViewController and PopupMenu VCs classes:

**Swift 4.0**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
        //... here is my VC code

    // showing Popup Menu VC
    @IBAction func showPopupMenu(sender: UIButton) {
        menuVC = PopupMenu()
        menuVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        menuVC?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 250)

        if let pvc = menuVC?.popoverPresentationController {
            pvc.permittedArrowDirections = .up
            pvc.delegate = self
            pvc.sourceView = sender
            pvc.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        }
        self.present(menuVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // showing VC from popupMenu VC
    @IBAction func showVCFromPopup(from target: PopupMenu, vc: UIViewController) {
        target.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) // dismiss popup

        if target.isBeingDismissed { // check is popup dismissed
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }

}// end of class

class PopupMenu: UIViewController {
    var button = UIButton()
    // here is init's 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //... some other code
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(vcOpen(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func vcOpen(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == button {
            let vc = UIViewController()
            if parent != nil { print("PARENT")} // Never will work, no ideas why, so MainVC isn't a parent of PopupMenu

            if let mainVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController {
                print("#  ACTION: Opening VC")
                mainVC.showVCFromPopup(target: self, as: vc!) // opening VC
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I have warning.
Maybe anyone will find mistakes in my code or have any ideas how to do this.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Could you provide the content of the function `openMenuVC`. And which line trigger your warning?

Comment: Sorry, `openMenuVC` func name is `showVCFromPopup`. I will add edits to my ask.

Line `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)` in `showVCFromPopup` func, but app not stopped only not presented a needed VC.

Comment: Did you try to present the controller on dismiss completion block?

Comment: @hasan83, Yes, I tried this variant, but also have same warning

Comment: @Y.Bonafons, I add edits to my code, and left comment above

Comment: There is something that doesn't make sense here. mainVC never presented. its an object in code only. and you are trying to present from it. its a new object not the old one.

Comment: did you do that because the parent property is nil? so you tried another way?

Comment: by the way parent is not the view controller that presented the controller. it is the one which contain it if any.

Comment: @hasan83, you mean that I call the NotPresented VC? No, I call the VC from storyboard and this VC is initial for app, so it presents every time when app starts.

Comment: @hasan83, yes, thanks, parent is a VC in which is an other VC like container or pageVC VC's.

Comment: ya but its another object. instantiateViewController creates new object not the one presented

Comment: I will add an answer. and lets see if it suite you

Comment: @hasan83, ohh... that changes all situation, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited you code to pass a reference of the mainVC to the PopupMenu:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    // showing Popup Menu VC
    @IBAction func showPopupMenu(sender: UIButton) {
        menuVC = PopupMenu()
        menuVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        menuVC?.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 250)

        menuVC?.MainVC = self <--- here

        if let pvc = menuVC?.popoverPresentationController {
            pvc.permittedArrowDirections = .up
            pvc.delegate = self
            pvc.sourceView = sender
            pvc.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        }
        self.present(menuVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class PopupMenu: UIViewController {
    var mainVC: UIViewController <-- here

    @IBAction func vcOpen(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == button {
            mainVC.showVCFromPopup(target: self, as: vc!) <-- here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but I don't know if you need to worry about reference cycling. think about it.